# Information Theoretic Measure: Entropy Calculation

Tags: python, statistics, entropy, information-theory, cross-entropy

I have a corpus consisting of thousands of lines. For the sake of simplicity, lets consider the corpus to be:

```
Today is a good day
I hope the day is good today
It's going to rain today
Today I have to study
```

How do I calculate the entropy using the corpus above ? The formula for the entropy is given as:

[image]

This is my understanding so far: Pi refers to the probability of the individual signs which calculated as `frequency(P) / (total num of characters)`. What I fail to understand is the summation ? I am not sure how summation works in this specific formula ?

I am using `Python 3.5.2` for the statistical data analysis. It would be really great if anybody could help me out with a code snippet for entropy calculation.

Comment: There must be a `numpy` method that performs a sum of a function of an array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SciPy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html to calculate entropy.

Or write something like that:

```
import math
def Entropy(string,base = 2.0):
    #make set with all unrepeatable symbols from string
    dct = dict.fromkeys(list(string))

    #calculate frequencies
    pkvec =  [float(string.count(c)) / len(string) for c in dct]

    #calculate Entropy
    H = -sum([pk  * math.log(pk) / math.log(base) for pk in pkvec ])
    return H


print(Entropy("Python is not so easy"))
```

It returns 3.27280432733.